# How to use SELECT INTO OUTFILE S3 to export into a S3 bucket in another AWS account and read from this other AWS account?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I would like to export data from RDS Aurora Mysql to a S3 bucket which is on another AWS account, then access the data from this another AWS account.

I have already managed to upload a file from Aurora Mysql to S3 following these two sets of instructions:

- [Saving data from an Amazon Aurora MySQL DB cluster into text files in an Amazon S3 bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.SaveIntoS3.html)
- [How can I provide cross-account access to objects that are in Amazon S3 buckets?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/)

However from the account on which the S3 bucket is, I can't download the objects. This problem is documented here: [Why can't I access an object that was uploaded to my Amazon S3 bucket by another AWS account?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-bucket-owner-access/)

There are possible solutions listed here: [When other AWS accounts upload objects to my Amazon S3 bucket, how can I require that they grant me full control of the objects?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-require-object-ownership/), but they don't apply to SELECT INTO OUTFILE S3 from Aurora Mysql since I can't add the option `--acl bucket-owner-full-control`

How could I setup my Aurora Mysql cluster so that the files uploaded to S3 with `SELECT INTO OUTFILE S3` on another AWS account could be read from there?

Comment: Sidenote: we have a similar issue with Kinesis Firehose, it cannot write with `bucket-owner-full-control` into an external bucket (additionally the ui breaks completely) and what we currently do is have a lambda in the target account, listening to the `ObjectCreated` events and then doing a self-copy of the object at which point it will properly belong to the target account.